# Quantum action, vertex function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, action

I am looking at Srednicki ch 64 , how does equation 64.1 follow from 64.3 as stated.

Explicitly in QED how does

$
u_{s'}(p')V^{u}(p',p)u_{s}(p)=e\bar{u'}(F_{1}(q^{2})\gamma ^{u}-\frac{i}{m}F_{2}(q^{2})S^{uv}q_{v})u
$

follow from

$$
\Gamma =\int d^{4}x(eF_{1}\bar{\varphi }\not{A}\varphi+\frac{e}{2m}F_{2}(0)F_{uv}\bar{\varphi }S^{uv}\varphi + ...
$$